# Laravel Pretty URL srt_replace does not work

Tags: php, laravel

i use this code for nav menu url's for pretty url, but for more 2 part words i have redirect page to 404 in laravel
but for one part words don't have problem

```
<a class="dropdown-item" href="/category/{{str_replace(' ', '_' , $cat_row->cat_name)}}">{{$cat_row->cat_name}}</a>
```

Comment: To be sure that you made it right, make one more unique column called `cat_slug` and store it on category save including logic of str_title, str_replace or whatever (personally, I'd make that in observer). Then, in dropdown when you call collection, you just put that (cat_slug) in URL. Don't make more than needed points of failure, control it in earliest stage possible.

Answer (score 0):

Because your routes doesn't exists. You should use a package to meet your needs.

One of the best packages for this is [Laravel Sluggable](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-sluggable)

This package provides a trait that will generate a unique slug when saving any Eloquent model.

```
$model = new EloquentModel();
$model->name = 'activerecord is awesome';
$model->save();

echo $model->slug; // ouputs "activerecord-is-awesome"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use your url look like this

```
<a class="dropdown-item" href="{{url('')}}/category/{{str_replace(' ', '_' , $cat_row->cat_name)}}">{{$cat_row->cat_name}}</a>
```